# Return website host url instead of api url

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx server with reverse proxy for my API. How can I return the website host URL instead of returning the API URL `api.example.com`, because when I make a request from website it returns the API URL not the website URL `app.example.com`.

```
        location /api/1 {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'updgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass https://api.example.com/rest;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
```

p/s: *sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change url in returned your application code and your application behind the proxy makes references to `api.example.com` instead of `app.example.com`, you need to change your application logic to return correct URL in this use case.

Or use [`sub_filter`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) module, But you need to check your nginx was built with this module.